# Dynamic length form with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to expand a basic angularjs form so that it can have a dynamic number of inputs. Basically I want to create a user that can have 1 or more siblings. If you click a + button on the form it will add an additional sibling input to the form and keep them as an array. What concepts would I use to accomplish this in angular?

How can I add elements to a partial view in angular when the user clicks?
And how can I make those inputs be kept as an array?

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    Siblings: <input type="text" ng-model="user.sibling[0]" /><br />
     <a href="#" name="moresiblings">+</a>
  </form>
  <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the siblings in `ng-repeat`

```
<span ng-repeat="sibling in user.siblings"><input type="text" ng-model="sibling" /></span>
```

Then when you add a new one push it to the `user.sblings` array in scope

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `ng-repeat` on the `sibling` inputs, and attaching an `ng-click` function to your `moresiblings` link that pushes new siblings into the `user.siblings` array. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/864/) that demonstrates the concept.